# Ext Dev Cannot set breakpoint during Debugging breakpoint set but not yet bound

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

I am developing a vscode extension.

The problem just started happening today, it's been running fine and not updated recently.

When stopped the breakpoint is active, filled and set, as soon as I Start Debugging, they all hollow and say "breakpoint set but not yet bound"

All breakpoints are said to be activated, but they never stop the flow.

I went back to 1.52, then Insiders, and they all do it.

As all versions are doing the same thing, I'm thinking it must be something I've done in my project, the question is what?  I've changed no settings, had no crashes.  Does anyone know what is going on?

Some other questions here suggest the launch settings, but these have not changed. I get the same unset points if I launch to run, launch to test, press F5.

Thanks.

```
Version: 1.53.0
Commit: 8490d3dde47c57ba65ec40dd192d014fd2113496
Date: 2021-02-03T16:01:04.046Z (5 days ago)
Electron: 11.2.1
Chrome: 87.0.4280.141
Node.js: 12.18.3
V8: 8.7.220.31-electron.0
OS: Darwin x64 19.6.0
```

Answer (score 0):

When I start debugging the Debug Console says
Congratulations, your extension "xml2json" is now active!
At this point, breakpoints are not bound, hollow circles.
I can wait for 10 minutes and nothing changes.

Then, if I select another file to open it in the editor, boom
The debug console spits out
Activated "bot-e"!
and the breakpoints come on.

While this is new behaviour, and something wrong almost not right somewhere in the universe, at least I can proceed, albeit needing to switch open files beforehand.